# Multiple sequence alignment file parsing

Tags: python, regex, biopython

I have a multiple sequence alignment file such as the the following

```
JF735120.1_1-200       TCTTCACGCAGAAAGCGTCTAGCCATGGCGTTAGTATGAGTGTCGTACAGCCTCCAGGCC
NC_009823.1_1-200      TCTTCACGCAGAAAGCGTCTAGCCATGGCGTTAGTATGAGTGTCGTACAGCCTCCAGGCC
KM349851.1_1-200       TCTTCACGCAGAAAGCGTCTAGCCATGGCGTTAGTATGAGTGTCGTACAGCCTCCAGGCC
JF735122.1_1-200       TCTTCACGCGGAAAGCGTCTAGCCATGGCGTTAGTACGAGTGTCGTGCAGCCTCCAGGCC
AF177036.1_1-200       --TTCACGCAGAAAGCGTCTAGCCATGGCGTTAGTATGAGTGTCGTACAGCCTCCAGGAC
                         ******* ******* ****************** ********* *********** *
```

using python how do I iterate over the file find asterisk sign and print only the previous line at the same position of the asterisk? without the use of any tools.
output should be like

```
TTCACGC

GAAAGCG

CTAGCCATGGCGTTAGTA

GAGTGTCGT

CAGCCTCCAGG

C
```

Comment: Do you want all previous line (ex: 5 `TTCACGC` for first `*******`), or just one previous line (ex 1 `TTCACGC` for first `*******`)?

Comment: Example output for your example input would be useful to see.

Comment: something like

["TTCACGC","GAAAGCG","CTAGCCATGGCGTTAGTA","GAGTGTCGT","CAGCCTCCAGG","C"] 

and possibly with the start and end position of each

Answer (score 4):

file content `c:/test.txt`

```
JF735120.1_1-200       TCTTCACGCAGAAAGCGTCTAGCCATGGCGTTAGTATGAGTGTCGTACAGCCTCCAGGCC
NC_009823.1_1-200      TCTTCACGCAGAAAGCGTCTAGCCATGGCGTTAGTATGAGTGTCGTACAGCCTCCAGGCC
KM349851.1_1-200       TCTTCACGCAGAAAGCGTCTAGCCATGGCGTTAGTATGAGTGTCGTACAGCCTCCAGGCC
JF735122.1_1-200       TCTTCACGCGGAAAGCGTCTAGCCATGGCGTTAGTACGAGTGTCGTGCAGCCTCCAGGCC
AF177036.1_1-200       --TTCACGCAGAAAGCGTCTAGCCATGGCGTTAGTATGAGTGTCGTACAGCCTCCAGGAC
                         ******* ******* ****************** ********* *********** *
```

```
import re

p = re.compile('[*]+')

prev_l=""
with open('c:/test.txt') as my_file:
    for line in my_file:
        if re.match('[\s*]+',line) and prev_l:
            iterator = p.finditer(line)
            f=[prev_l[match.start():match.end()] for match in iterator]
            f
        else:
            prev_l=line
```

results

```
['TTCACGC', 'GAAAGCG', 'CTAGCCATGGCGTTAGTA', 'GAGTGTCGT', 'CAGCCTCCAGG', 'C']
```

another option with spaces

```
import re

p = re.compile('[*]+')

prev_l=""
p_end=0
with open('c:/test.txt') as my_file:
    for line in my_file:
        if re.match('[\s*]+',line) and prev_l:
            iterator = p.finditer(line)
            f=[]
            p=[]
            for match in iterator:
                f.append(prev_l[match.start():match.end()])
                if p_end != 0:
                    p.append(prev_l[p_end:match.start()])
                else:
                    if prev_l[match.start()-1] != '-':
                        p.append(prev_l[match.start()-1:match.start()])
                p_end=match.end()
            if p_end != len(prev_l):
                p.append(prev_l[p_end:len(prev_l)])
            p
            f
        else:
            prev_l=line.rstrip('\n')
```

results

```
['A', 'T', 'T', 'A', 'A']
['TTCACGC', 'GAAAGCG', 'CTAGCCATGGCGTTAGTA', 'GAGTGTCGT', 'CAGCCTCCAGG', 'C']
```

Comment: Very clever answer.

Comment: @arutar Thank you so much. I am sorry but if want the opposite of that, meaning only getting the dissimilar regions where there are no asterisks below, how could it be done?

Comment: Is it possible that the first character in the sequence will be a space and not an asterisk?

Comment: i added another option